# Converting xcdatamodel to sqllite db file

Tags: objective-c, xcode, sqlite

Is there any way to perform converting `.xcdatamodel` to `sqlite3 .db` file to get ability to open `.db` file in a "terminal"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the data at runtime and export it out. Call:

```
NSURL *appDir = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
NSURL *storeURL = [appDir URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"nameofyourmodel.sqlite"];
```

Then you can use `NSFileManager` to find and export it.